# How to get multiselect to display more elements?

Tags: jquery, multi-select

I'm using the jquery.multiselect package to good effect, however, I have one <select> widget which contains more than 60 <options>. When I click the button, I'd like to see more than the default number of entries. Currently, only six are displayed. How might I get it to display 10 (or more) entries? I tried setting size="10" in the <select> widget, but that had no effect.

I also can't seem to find any documentation. Does any exist beyond the demos?

Comment: Please specify which jQuery plugin you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Most jQuery select enhancement plugins convert the select element to a list. Simply modify its height:

```
ul.mySelect {height: 400px;}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm a total jQuery (in fact, JavaScript) naif, but that seems to move the abstraction in the wrong direction. Shouldn't the units of the height be related to the content of the select widget, not screen units? Can I sort of drag it back into the realm of content by using "em" as the units?

Comment: Certainly. Any value that's valid CSS. You haven't answered my question above, though, so I don't even know if I'm on the right track here.

Comment: Sorry, I was busy with other stuff yesterday. Your css didn't quite work, but gives me the direction in which to search. Looking at the jquery.multiselect.js code, it appears it always manipulates the height without referring to any units, which suggests to me that "px" are always assumed. I'm not up for modifying (and likely breaking) my copy right now, so I will just go with the flow and change the default height to a larger value. Thx...